# How to filter approvers based on location?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, approval-process

I am using SharePoint On-Prem 2019 and have Nitro Studio hosting my sites. One site I have manages the purchasing system, and I would like to filter the approvers based on location. I already have worflows set up for multilevel approval, but we have offices in different areas each with their own Manager, so I would like to set each Location Manager as a Level 1 approver and set it to where Location gets factored into the approval process.

Example: Someone at Office A submits a purchase request, and the level one approver is the Office A manager. How can I set it so that only Manager A gets the request instead of all managers?

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat familiar with Nitro Studio / Crow Canyon, and I would highly suggest calling them for support.  Their system does not work like OOTB SharePoint, and messing with their processes easily breaks stuff from my experience.

OOTB SharePoint I would do this with a lookup list that the workflow looks to and grabs the approvers per your location field.  i.e have you lookup list with columns for location, and approver.  Then have your workflow read the location from the purchase request form, and pull the approver from the lookup list.